# Move <Script> content to a separate JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have working code to update a video id. However, when I moved all my JS code from the script tag to a JS file, the code breaks. The code does not load, so iframe api does not load and the on click events do not execute.

```
 <Script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId:  '{{no-video-id}}',
      events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
                           });
  }


  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    $('.open-popup').click(function() {
      event.target.playVideo();
    });

    $('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
      player.stopVideo();
    });

  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {           
      $('.close.close-popup').click();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }

 $(function () { 
   $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
      $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
      var x = new String(bookId);
      player.loadVideoById(x); 

  });


  $('#video-player-1').click(function(e) {
       var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
      var x = new String(bookId);
      player.loadVideoById(x);
      alert("HEELO");
      });

  $( "#video-player-2" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
});
</script>
```

This is the JS fiddle showing the  code moved into a separate file.
https://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/7313/

When I click the  tag, I get "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'player.loadVideoById')" in the console

UPDATE Solution: Add `<script src="youtube.com/iframe_api">`  in html https://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/7325/

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: When I click, I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'player.loadVideoById')

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with moving the JS to an external file as far as I can see. Ask yourself where `player` *should* be defined and why that might not be happening.

Comment: @Quentin, if I move all my js code into the script tag, it does work.

Comment: Still nothing to do with being in an external file. Look at what JS Fiddle is configured (by default) to do with the code you pasted into the JS pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call onYouTubeIframeAPIReady method after loading complete, html takes time to load. and your player is undefined. [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/ssorabh/k7FC2/7324/)

```
$(function () { 
// call onYoutubeIframeAPIReady method when you have access to all html
 onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(); // add this line
   $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
      $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
      var x = new String(bookId);
      player.loadVideoById(x); 

  });


  $('#video-player-1').click(function(e) {
       var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
      var x = new String(bookId);
      player.loadVideoById(x);
      alert("HEELO");
      });

  $( "#video-player-2" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
});
```

and add script tag

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Comment: The code adds a iframe to the modal, so if the code is working, you should see a youtube video play. You had a good idea, but does not fix the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2012677 now YT is undefined, let me see where that come from. That also trying to declared before html even loaded.

Comment: I read that maybe I need to add "window." to the api function, but not sure how to modify this code to do that. https://chromatichq.com/blog/working-youtube-player-api-iframe-embeds

Comment: Please check link now it is working now. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ssorabh/k7FC2/7322/) . here i just added script tag directly to html

Comment: @user2012677 You was dynamically loading script using javascript, but here you didn't have any callback to track to api load complete. so i just move it to as part of html means it will be available at jQuery loadcomplete

Comment: ok it didn't update you just add <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api">

</script>  in html.